# How to make an image responsive on PS4?

Tags: css

I was on the console viewing a site I was working on and noticed my banners looked off.

```
<div class="blog-post-featured-banner">
        <img width="1600" height="900" src="#">
</div>

.blog-post-featured-banner {
    height: 50vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}
.blog-post-featured-banner img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

It looks fine on desktop, but when I view it on my PS4 it looks like the img had `height:100%;`, it looked squished. I expected it to behave the way it does on desktop, it takes 100% width of the screen and the height is hidden in the overflow. Given I'm viewing it on a TV I expected it to get a bit pixelated. Could it just be needing a very large image? The TV is 55".

Sort of a side question, but in the div that holds the image, I was trying to make the image vertically and horizontally centered in the "frame", how could I adjust my css to do so, if possible.

Comment: I guess it's compatibility issues .. could be the use of [Flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) or the [VH Units](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

Comment: Hi Darren, just to mention : Length units representing 1% of the viewport size for viewport width (vw), height (vh), the smaller of the two (vmin), or the larger of the two (vmax).

Also, that the PS4 is the first to include a WebKit-based web browser, which is a departure from its predecessor, which uses the NetFront browser; it is based on the same modern WebKit core as Google Chrome and Apple Safari.

So, look at your 'viewport' detection might be a way to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

The browser that Playstation use might not support viewport units. The viewport units are gaining support on all modern browsers, however, there are some cases where this unit is not supported or bugs have been found.

Try setting the html and body tag's height to 100%. Then set your "blog-post-featured-banner" height to 50%. This should replicate what you are trying to achieve currently.

```
<div class="blog-post-featured-banner">
     <img width="1600" height="900" src="#">
</div>

html, body {
    height: 100%
}

.blog-post-featured-banner {
    height: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}
.blog-post-featured-banner img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a friend look at this. My side question sort of led to the answer, not saying what you guys answered was incorrect, but this did what I wanted.

```
<div class="blog-post-featured-banner">
        <div class="featured-banner" style="background: url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url( 'full' ); ?> ) no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">
</div>

.blog-post-featured-banner {
    height: 50vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.featured-banner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The `50vh` seemed to work on the PS4's browser.